# Verb form in Esperanto Cooking Recipes

Tags: verbs

How are cooking recipes written in Esperanto?

Cooking recipes are a very special genre with respect to verb form, in German (my mother tongue) the infinitive is used as a substitute for the imperative (very old style). An intermediate style was characterised by the impersonal pronoun *man* "oni" with subjunctive (German *Man nehme ...* "Oni prenus ...").

Comment: Just a nerdy note one the German subjunctive here: It has the value of a volitive in such a context, so _man nehme_ = _oni prenu_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nenio pli bongusta ol [vera retejo](https://apetito.ikso.net/recepto/crumble-kun-fragoj-kaj-rabarbo). Tie mi vidis kaj `-i` infinitivo kaj `-u` volitivo. La `-u` formo pli taŭgas.